Dynamic image in Splash Screen API
I have to create a splash screen in my app where dynamic image will be displayed. Image will be downloaded from the server and cached locally. I want to use splash screen API but after going through the document it say image need to be retrieve from the xml file. Is it possible that the image of splash screen can be loaded dynamically using the Splash screen API.
Here is the document of Splash Screen API
https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/launch/splash-screen

Splash Screen API does not have the direct support for loading an image at runtime (e. g. , from a server). This has to be available at compile-time because the image is associated with the theme that the system employs to show the splash screen. The static placeholder image must be put by using the Splash Screen API, then, to accomplish the dynamic change of the image in Android – implement the API mentioned above. In another custom splash screen activity, download the image from the url and store it locally in the device using Glide. After image is displayed, open the main activity.

The role of the splash screen is not to load images from the server. If the server crashes or the internet is slow or unable to get the response, it won't be very worthwhile. You can also use Lottie Animation for the SplashScreen.

@Bob So it is not possible to show dynamic image using Splash Screen API. I need to create custom Splash Screen and load the image using Glide?

yes create custom splash screen
